# Is Honour killing and other painful punishment such as walking bear footed on fire are allowed in Islam?

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh

In our society specially in some tribes honour killing is consider as pride. Every many innocent women are killed due to misconception.Some time to prove the innocence victim has to walk bear footed on the fire.What Islam says about this issue specially about innocent victims and the person who clam for honour killing and blame the victim??

Comment: The concept of proofs of innocence like these have a non-Islamic background. For example in which-hunts or inquisition the European middle ages ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , **First** Islam has very rigid rules when it comes to establishing accusations and proving innocence , especially for adultery related matters .
Now , I believe you understand that adultery in Islam is no laughing matter as adultery for a married person is a guaranteed death sentence (stoning)  , that's why ,naturally, sharia law has many procedures to regulate accusations of adultery or of any similarly morally deviant act , like the witnesses who must have witnessed the act , or a personal confession , etc. ...
That's what makes your description of what passes for Sharia law in tribal communities sound incredibly conspicuous , cherry-picking proceedings of  Sharia law is a very dangerous path . Honor killings ,by virtue, are ridden with prejudice and a complete disregard for evidence as well as complete lack of understanding of Sharia law (its proceedings are often bypassed without a second thought) which is just so wholly unIslamic that I find it ludicrous that it's even attributed to Islam .
**So to answer your question** : No , honor killings are more tribal than Islamic , Islam has a far more complex legal system that establishes crime and punishment .

**Second** : Fire walking is a [pagan tradition](https://www.britannica.com/topic/fire-walking) and has nothing to do with Islam .